# SQLALCHEMY: When is the with_for_update() lock released

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

does it just get released on session.commit()? I couldn't find documentation on the release of the lock

Comment: This is not something inherent to SQLAlchemy, but the DB you're using (int this case Postgresql). Read https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html. "Once acquired, a lock is normally held till end of transaction. But if a lock is acquired after establishing a savepoint, the lock is released immediately if the savepoint is rolled back to."

Comment: yes, this does look like a duplicate, my bad. was looking for something sqlalchemy related